# Should I log transform a right skewed continuous variable in Weibull AFT model?

Tags: survival

Suppose I have a Weibull AFT Model or any other AFT models such as:

```
survreg(Surv(time, censor) ~ a right skewed continuous variable,
        data =  sub, dist = "weibull")
```

Should I log transform this right skewed continuous variable?

I found that the `AIC` and `BIC` are still the same after transformation. However, I have not yet seen any AFT models actually have any transformed covariates. However, the response variable is like Y = log(T).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to because the Weibull pdf can be skewed depending on the values of the location and scale parameters.  AFT regression packages will determine the maximum likelihood values of location and scale, which will represent the underlying hazard rate over time.  [image: [1]]